# Cart item delete hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a hook when a item/product is removed from the cart, where I could get any information what so ever about that item? Tried google and  did not find anything good.

Comment: Your best bet is to read the source code. This sounds somewhat familiar to me. Voila... [remove_cart_item()](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L977) method.

Answer (score 1):

woocommerce_cart_updatedI found a solution in handling the get values passes when item is deleted

```
function remove_from_cart() {

    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

    if ( isset( $_GET[ 'remove_item' ] ) ){

        $cart_item_key = $_GET[ 'remove_item' ];

    }       
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_updated', 'remove_from_cart' );
```